# How do I not crash Intune Wrapped App during startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

We have a react-native app ejected and built on iOS using xcode. This app is then wrapped using Intune App Wrap tool (version 12.3.1) and deployed through Intune or Microsoft Endpoint manager.

When we start the app, it tries for network connection and crashes. It displays "checking your organization's data access requirements for this app" and crashes immediately

Are we missing some basic Intune MDM configuration or is this a bug using MS Intune app wrapper.?

Trace log files from Console:

error   15:23:17.807684-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  nw_socket_connect [C1:2] connectx(6 (guarded), [srcif=0, srcaddr=, dstaddr=], SAE_ASSOCID_ANY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, SAE_CONNID_ANY) failed: [1: Operation not permitted]
error   15:23:17.808140-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  nw_socket_connect  connectx failed (fd 6) [1: Operation not permitted]
error   15:23:17.809405-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  nw_socket_connect connectx failed [1: Operation not permitted]
error   15:23:17.810324-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  Connection 1: received failure notification
error   15:23:17.810834-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  Connection 1: failed to connect 1:1, reason -1
error   15:23:17.814640-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  Connection 1: encountered error(1:1)
error   15:23:17.839080-0400    Automated Contractor Estimator  Task .<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: 1 [1:1])

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into a similar issue and curious what the solution is